# Spring boot API with JWT authentication called twice

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, jwt, websecurity

My spring endpoint is being called twice when using JWT authentication. As you can see below the API request is called twice before completing.

```
2023-09-16 20:57:12.819 DEBUG 5531 --- [nio-7171-exec-9] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : Securing GET /api/private/getUserByEmail?email=k@test.com
2023-09-16 20:57:12.819 DEBUG 5531 --- [nio-7171-exec-9] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=hype.security.keycloak.UserPrincipal@175b01b7, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[]]]
2023-09-16 20:57:12.819 DEBUG 5531 --- [nio-7171-exec-9] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=hype.security.keycloak.UserPrincipal@175b01b7, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[]]]
2023-09-16 20:57:12.820 DEBUG 5531 --- [nio-7171-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [GET /api/private/getUserByEmail?email=k@test.com] with attributes [authenticated]
2023-09-16 20:57:12.820 DEBUG 5531 --- [nio-7171-exec-9] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : Secured GET /api/private/getUserByEmail?email=k@test.com
email k@test.com
Hibernate: select user0_.`email` as email1_4_, user0_.`code` as code2_4_, user0_.`country` as country3_4_, user0_.`f_name` as f_name4_4_, user0_.`l_name` as l_name5_4_, user0_.`phone` as phone6_4_ from `user` user0_ where user0_.`email`=?
Hibernate: select companies0_.`email` as email1_5_0_, companies0_.`company_id` as company_2_5_0_, company1_.`company_id` as company_1_1_1_, company1_.`active` as active2_1_1_, company1_.`company` as company3_1_1_, company1_.`companyurl` as companyu4_1_1_, company1_.`country` as country5_1_1_, company1_.`created_on` as created_6_1_1_, company1_.`paid` as paid7_1_1_, company1_.`role` as role8_1_1_, company1_.`stripe_id` as stripe_i9_1_1_, company1_.`tier` as tier10_1_1_ from `users_companies` companies0_ inner join `company` company1_ on companies0_.`company_id`=company1_.`company_id` where companies0_.`email`=?
2023-09-16 20:57:12.825 DEBUG 5531 --- [nio-7171-exec-9] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=hype.security.keycloak.UserPrincipal@12355d25, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@10d216fb]
2023-09-16 20:57:12.826 DEBUG 5531 --- [nio-7171-exec-9] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : Secured GET /api/private/getUserByEmail?email=k@test.com
email k@test.com
Hibernate: select user0_.`email` as email1_4_, user0_.`code` as code2_4_, user0_.`country` as country3_4_, user0_.`f_name` as f_name4_4_, user0_.`l_name` as l_name5_4_, user0_.`phone` as phone6_4_ from `user` user0_ where user0_.`email`=?
Hibernate: select companies0_.`email` as email1_5_0_, companies0_.`company_id` as company_2_5_0_, company1_.`company_id` as company_1_1_1_, company1_.`active` as active2_1_1_, company1_.`company` as company3_1_1_, company1_.`companyurl` as companyu4_1_1_, company1_.`country` as country5_1_1_, company1_.`created_on` as created_6_1_1_, company1_.`paid` as paid7_1_1_, company1_.`role` as role8_1_1_, company1_.`stripe_id` as stripe_i9_1_1_, company1_.`tier` as tier10_1_1_ from `users_companies` companies0_ inner join `company` company1_ on companies0_.`company_id`=company1_.`company_id` where companies0_.`email`=?
2023-09-16 20:57:12.830 DEBUG 5531 --- [nio-7171-exec-9] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=hype.security.keycloak.UserPrincipal@12355d25, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@10d216fb]
2023-09-16 20:57:12.830 DEBUG 5531 --- [nio-7171-exec-9] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

I compared this against an endpoint that is publicly exposed (same method but without JWT). It gets called only once.

```
2023-09-16 20:59:39.992 DEBUG 5531 --- [nio-7171-exec-6] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : Securing GET /api/public/getUserByEmail2?email=k@test.com
2023-09-16 20:59:39.992 DEBUG 5531 --- [nio-7171-exec-6] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=hype.security.keycloak.UserPrincipal@12355d25, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[]]]
2023-09-16 20:59:39.992 DEBUG 5531 --- [nio-7171-exec-6] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=hype.security.keycloak.UserPrincipal@12355d25, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[]]]
2023-09-16 20:59:39.992 DEBUG 5531 --- [nio-7171-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [GET /api/public/getUserByEmail2?email=k@test.com] with attributes [permitAll]
2023-09-16 20:59:39.992 DEBUG 5531 --- [nio-7171-exec-6] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : Secured GET /api/public/getUserByEmail2?email=k@test.com
email k@test.com
Hibernate: select user0_.`email` as email1_4_, user0_.`code` as code2_4_, user0_.`country` as country3_4_, user0_.`f_name` as f_name4_4_, user0_.`l_name` as l_name5_4_, user0_.`phone` as phone6_4_ from `user` user0_ where user0_.`email`=?
Hibernate: select companies0_.`email` as email1_5_0_, companies0_.`company_id` as company_2_5_0_, company1_.`company_id` as company_1_1_1_, company1_.`active` as active2_1_1_, company1_.`company` as company3_1_1_, company1_.`companyurl` as companyu4_1_1_, company1_.`country` as country5_1_1_, company1_.`created_on` as created_6_1_1_, company1_.`paid` as paid7_1_1_, company1_.`role` as role8_1_1_, company1_.`stripe_id` as stripe_i9_1_1_, company1_.`tier` as tier10_1_1_ from `users_companies` companies0_ inner join `company` company1_ on companies0_.`company_id`=company1_.`company_id` where companies0_.`email`=?
2023-09-16 20:59:39.996 DEBUG 5531 --- [nio-7171-exec-6] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

My WebConfig file

```
package hype.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoders;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

import hype.security.authentication.CompositeAuthenticationFilter;
import hype.security.authentication.apikey.ApiKeyAuthenticationFilter;
import hype.security.authentication.apikey.ApiKeyAuthenticationProvider;
import hype.security.authentication.jwt.JwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter;
import hype.security.authentication.jwt.JwtBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider;
import hype.security.handlers.CustomAccessDeniedHandler;
import hype.service.KeycloakService;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Order(1)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String jwtIssuerUri;

    @Value("${api-private.pattern}")
    private String apiPrivatePattern;

    @Value("${api-public.pattern}")
    private String apiPublicPattern;

    @Value("${ignoring.patterns}")
    private String[] ignoringPatterns;

    @Value("${file.extensions}")
    private String[] fileExtensions;

    @Value("${content-security-policy}")
    private String contentSecurityPolicy;

    @Value("${api-key-request-pattern}")
    private String requestPattern;

    @Autowired
    KeycloakService keycloakService;

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(jwtIssuerUri);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider jwtBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new JwtBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(apiKeyAuthenticationProvider())
                .authenticationProvider(jwtBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public ApiKeyAuthenticationProvider apiKeyAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new ApiKeyAuthenticationProvider(keycloakService);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApiKeyAuthenticationFilter apiKeyAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        ApiKeyAuthenticationFilter apiKeyAuthenticationFilter = new ApiKeyAuthenticationFilter(requestPattern);
        apiKeyAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return apiKeyAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter jwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        return new JwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter(apiPrivatePattern, jwtDecoder(), authenticationManagerBean());
    }

    @Bean
    public CompositeAuthenticationFilter compositeAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        String[] permittedUrlPatterns = { apiPublicPattern }; // Add more patterns if needed
        return new CompositeAuthenticationFilter(apiKeyAuthenticationFilter(), jwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter(), permittedUrlPatterns);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(ignoringPatterns);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(apiPublicPattern).permitAll().antMatchers(fileExtensions)
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .addFilterBefore(compositeAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/expired").sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler()).and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().headers().contentSecurityPolicy(contentSecurityPolicy);
    }

}
```

My compositeFilter.java

```
package hype.security.authentication;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import hype.security.authentication.apikey.ApiKeyAuthenticationFilter;
import hype.security.authentication.jwt.JwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter;

public class CompositeAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private ApiKeyAuthenticationFilter apiKeyAuthenticationFilter;
    private JwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter jwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter;

    @Value("${private-api-key-uri}")
    private String privateApiUri;


    @Value("${private-api-uri}")
    private String privateApiKeyUri;

    // Add this property for permitted URLs
    private final OrRequestMatcher permittedRequestMatcher;

    // Update the constructor to accept the permitted URLs patterns
    public CompositeAuthenticationFilter(ApiKeyAuthenticationFilter apiKeyAuthenticationFilter,
                                         JwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter jwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter,
                                         String[] permittedUrlPatterns) {
        this.apiKeyAuthenticationFilter = apiKeyAuthenticationFilter;
        this.jwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter = jwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter;
        this.permittedRequestMatcher = createOrRequestMatcher(permittedUrlPatterns);
    }

    // Add this method to create an OrRequestMatcher for the permitted URLs
    private OrRequestMatcher createOrRequestMatcher(String[] patterns) {
        List<RequestMatcher> matchers = Arrays.stream(patterns)
                .map(AntPathRequestMatcher::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new OrRequestMatcher(matchers);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return permittedRequestMatcher.matches(request);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Authentication apiKeyAuthResult = apiKeyAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
        if (apiKeyAuthResult != null && apiKeyAuthResult.isAuthenticated()) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(apiKeyAuthResult);
            apiKeyAuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication(request, response, filterChain, apiKeyAuthResult);
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            Authentication bearerTokenAuthResult = jwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(request,
                    response);
            if (bearerTokenAuthResult != null && bearerTokenAuthResult.isAuthenticated()) {
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(bearerTokenAuthResult);
                jwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication(request, response, filterChain, bearerTokenAuthResult);
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                System.out.println("request:" + request.getRequestURI());
                if (request.getRequestURI().startsWith(privateApiUri) || request.getRequestURI().startsWith(privateApiKeyUri)) {
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                    String contentType = request.getContentType();
                    if (contentType == null) {
                        contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;
                    }

                    if (contentType.equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)) {
                        response.getWriter().write("{\"message\": \"Unauthorized\"}");
                    } else if (contentType.equals(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)) {
                        response.getWriter().write("Unauthorized");
                    } else {
                        // You can add support for other content types here
                    }
                    response.setContentType(contentType);
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                } else {
                    String contentType = request.getContentType();
                    if (contentType == null) {
                        contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;
                    }
                    response.setContentType(contentType);
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My JWTFilter

```
package hype.security.authentication.jwt;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter;

import hype.security.keycloak.UserPrincipal;

public class JwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private final JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

    public JwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl, JwtDecoder jwtDecoder,
            AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
        this.jwtDecoder = jwtDecoder;
        setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            Optional<String> bearerToken = extractBearerToken(request);
            if (bearerToken.isPresent()) {
                Jwt jwt = jwtDecoder.decode(bearerToken.get());
                Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Collections.emptyList(); // Optionally, map authorities from
                                                                                    // JWT claims
                UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(jwt.getSubject());
                Authentication authentication = new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, userPrincipal, authorities);
                return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.warn("JWT authentication failed: {}");
        }

        return null;
    }

    private Optional<String> extractBearerToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return Optional.of(authorizationHeader.substring(7));
        } else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you enable debug mode by setting `@EnableWebSecurity(debug=true)` , and then re-execute both cases and update the logs . Also , can you also add some log in all filters that you created (e.g CompositeAuthenticationFilter ,JwtBearerTokenAuthenticationFilter etc) at the first line of `doFilterInternal()` to verify that these filter are really execute or not ?